# gradle checkstyle just output warn, but build sucess

Tags: java, gradle, checkstyle

as you can see the checkstyle warn,but the build of this time is still success. why? I want it faild. please help.

```
D:\MyData\xxxx>gradle clean checkstyleMain
:clean
:compileJava
:processResources
:classes
:checkstyleMain
[ant:checkstyle] [WARN] D:\MyData\xxxx.java:218:18: Member name 'Aource' 
must match pattern '^[a-z][a-z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9]*$'. [MemberName]

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 4.966 secs
```

```

see the img: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7IbRM.jpg

see the checkstyle.xml: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BE4An.jpg

Comment: Could you provide the checkstyle configuration you're using?

Comment: [https://i.stack.imgur.com/BE4An.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BE4An.jpg) thank you

Answer (score 8, accepted):

EDIT: There is better solution since I wrote that answer -> use `maxErrors=0` as **xxSwordy** mentioned here https://stackoverflow.com/a/57141028/3464596.

Here is PR: https://github.com/gradle/gradle/pull/3901

There is possible to do it for errors by:

`ignoreFailures = false`

For warnings, there **IS NOT POSSIBLE** to do that, see [this][1] ticket.

From their old Jira and new GitHub issue comments there is one workaround:

```
tasks.withType(Checkstyle).each { checkstyleTask ->
    checkstyleTask.doLast {
        reports.all { report ->
            def outputFile = report.destination
            if (outputFile.exists() && outputFile.text.contains("<error ")) {
                throw new GradleException("There were checkstyle warnings! For more info check $outputFile")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**So answer is: This is not possible by default and there is still opened ticket for that.** If you really WANT IT, you can try to participate and try to fix it, Gradle is opensource and it depends on developers :)
[1]: https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/881

Comment: Tried with what? ignoreFailures working only for ERRORS, I addded workaround for warnings, but it is from comments in their github, maybe you should look there. By In a fact, it's NOT possible to do that :)

Comment: No problem :) I didnt try their workarounds, maybe guys there will be able to help you with their workaround :)

Comment: Oh,I was the first use the gradle,hahahaha.   and I want to ask anthor question:

Comment: question is now I update to your provide code, then it doesn't to display the warn code position,just display "There were checkstyle warnings! For more info check $outputFile"  outputfile is the reportfile location

Comment: I think I dont understand, what is question?

Comment: oh, I found the code warn position. It's my mistake. so sorry.

Comment: Ok, so if you think this answer is correct for you, accept the answer and i wish you do well with gradle ;)

Comment: This comment here seems answer the question better: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57141028/10746857

Answer (score 25):

Sorry for grave-digging but I just stumbled across this while trying to achieve the same thing. Turns out that this has now been implemented, but requires a tiny configuration change.

So for any future adventures finding their way here: in your `build.gradle` to the following:

```
checkstyle {
  ignoreFailures = false
  maxWarnings = 0
}
```

This will then cause your builds to fail on Checkstyle errors.

Comment: Do you need the checkstyle plugin or something for this? Fails my build w/ "Could not find method checkstyle() for arguments ..."

Comment: Thanks for this it was exactly what we needed.
Thanks for also looking out for posterity.

Comment: For whatever reason, this did not work for me. Am using gradle 6.9.1 and checkstyle 8.37. What worked instead was the workaround below https://stackoverflow.com/a/44843985/2200690

Answer (score 10):

The default severity level for checkstyle violations is a warning. If you want the build to fail change the severity value from warning to error in your checkstyle.xml configuration. Any subsequent build will now fail if a violation exists.

```
<property name="severity" value="error"/>
```

Comment: This is the better answer to me. It's more intuitive to see ERRORs instead of WARNs when the build fails due to failed checkstyle checks.